# Why does my email action only show this?

Tags: email, administration

Our relatively new org, actually about a year old, but only recently discussed sending emails from within Salesforce, shows the following within the email action?

I believe we had a choice to send via a 3rd party service (Office 365/Gmail) or use Salesforce.  I believe Salesforce was clicked by an admin and now everyones email action looks like this.  Any ideas on how we can enable it?

I did note a setting under "My Email Settings" for each user that defines which email editor to use - ultimately changing it made no difference.

[image: email action image]

Answer (score 0):

This could be a browser-related issue.

Could you refer to this [article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000318129&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1) and cross-check the recommendations in resolution section ?

Comment: I'll have a look at the article, what's werid is I have another tab open with a different org logged in - works fine...different org, different license etc but the email features are all good.

Comment: Are you a system admin in the org having the issue ? it might be a bug if this is occurring for admin also, I suggest to log a case with salesforce support in parallel